# C# will Dispose still get called in this situation?

Tags: c#, dispose, using, idisposable

Is the following code the same, eg will dispose still get called?

If I use a using statement, like this, I know Dispose will get called:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procedureName, sqlConnection))
{
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   if (sqlParams != null)
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams.ToArray());

   SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   return rdr;
}
```

My question is, is the effectively the same thing:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procedureName, sqlConnection)
using (cmd)
{
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   if (sqlParams != null)
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams.ToArray());

   SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   return rdr;
}
```

Comment: why not simply try it out by debugging?

Comment: It's not a mysterious black box. You can read the [language spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-using-statement) and realise that `cmd` in your second example is just a (very simple) expression.

Comment: @HimBromBeere that is a fair point. I cannot step into this class but I after I posted this question I did that with another class and I know it does call dispose.

Comment: As long as you don't put any code between the creation and the `using` then this should be fine, but if you did put something between them and that threw an exception then it would not get disposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - anything you can call Dispose() on will be disposed of automatically when the code exits the using() block, including in the example you give above.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can decide :)

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        using(cmd)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "Test command";
            Console.WriteLine("Inside using block-- " +cmd.CommandText);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Outside using block --" +cmd.CommandText);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Output:
Inside using block-- Test command

Outside using block --Test command

Updated for more clarity:
Dispose will be called for sure, the difference on both examples is with the second one you will be able to access the properties set by the object in the using block.

Comment: your answer is correct but LordPupazz was first so I marked him as correct. I did upvote you though

Comment: This does not prove whether dispose was called. Dispose is usually meant to dispose of unmanaged resources. CommandText is a string and not an unmanaged resource. The Dispose is called.

Comment: I tried to highlight difference on both examples, with the first one you can't use commandText or other properties of same object outside the block. Agreed with that dispose will be called.